# Applying Routing rules fired message in Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, message, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

What's the message fired when we apply routing rules on a case record? I need to add plugin that  create a task automatically for the new owner.

Answer (score 0):

There is a global action - `ApplyRoutingRule` introduced in 2016 version.

For 2015, you can listen to QueueItem create message or Assign message (user/team) based on your implementation.